# How to use Wget with TMG proxy without username and password

Tags: proxy, wget

I am behind a proxy (TMG server) that doesn't need username/password. Can i use wget with this unauthenticated proxy? apt-get works fine but i am unable to get wget to work. I have modified wgetrc and also used http_proxy but to no avail. Is it that wget always need username/password?

please guide me in resolving this or suggest an alternative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring wget proxy

Add below lines in file ~/.wgetrc or /etc/wgetrc:

```
http_proxy = http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
https_proxy = http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
ftp_proxy = http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
use_proxy = on
```

Add below lines in file ~/.bash_profile or /etc/profile:

```
export http_proxy=http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
export https_proxy=http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
export ftp_proxy=http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, i had already added above lines. issue i think is with the TMG without authentication.

Comment: @Shoaib: Yes, according to Microsoft this problem occurs because of the DNS-based load balancing algorithm.
When a proxy client opens a website and resolves the name to Yes and attempts to establish a connection (SSL) with the destination IP address, for example, IP-1.
TMG reads the subject fields of the retrieved certificate, tries to resolve it using DNS, checks if it matches the IP address.
Due to the resolved load balancing for the website, TMG provides a different IP address, IP-2, the IP addresses are not the same, and the connection is rejected.
You should check with them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. How shall I proceed then when I am behind a proxy. I have to download ODL. Should i use IPs instead of FQDN in URL?